# Scroll Multiple LazyRows together - LazyHorizontalGrid alike?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

How to assign the same scroll state to two LazyRows, so that both row scrolls together?

Jetpack compose [lists](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists) currently doesn't have LazyHorizontalGrid, So any alternative solution?

```kotlin
Column{
    LazyRow(                                                        
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()          
    ) {                                                              
        // My sublist1                                                           
    }
    LazyRow(                                                        
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()                         
    ) {                                                              
        // My sublist2                                                          
    }
}
```

**Trying to implement below**:

[image: sample horizontally scroll image]

Comment: Why don't you use a single `LazyRow`?  :/

Comment: @nglauber That is the design guideline, have to do it the same way.

Comment: Perhaps you could use [LazyVerticalGrid](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#LazyVerticalGrid(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.GridCells,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Function1))

Comment: @SandroKakhetelidze No, I require the Horizontally scrollable grid. There should be some way to make this work.

Comment: Actually, it has https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#lazy-grids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: Google has added the component officially - [LazyHorizontalGrid](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/grid/package-summary#LazyHorizontalGrid(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridCells,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)).

---

I modified the LazyVerticalGrid class, and made it work towards only `GridCells.Fixed(n)` horizontal grid.

Here is the complete gist code: [LazyHorizontalGrid.kt](https://gist.github.com/geekykant/47a89894dbc8086f4bcabe02fe525f0e)

[image: lazyhorizontalgrid]

**Main changes**

```kotlin
@Composable
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
private fun FixedLazyGrid(
    nRows: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    state: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState(),
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(0.dp),
    scope: LazyGridScopeImpl
) {
    val columns = (scope.totalSize + nRows - 1) / nRows
    LazyRow(
        modifier = modifier,
        state = state,
        contentPadding = contentPadding,
    ) {
        items(columns) { columnIndex ->
            Column {
                for (rowIndex in 0 until nRows) {
                    val itemIndex = columnIndex * nRows + rowIndex
                    if (itemIndex < scope.totalSize) {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(),
                            propagateMinConstraints = true
                        ) {
                            scope.contentFor(itemIndex, this@items).invoke()
                        }
                    } else {
                        Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f, fill = true))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Code Usage**

```kotlin
LazyHorizontalGrid(
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(2)
) {
    items(items = restaurantsList){
        RestaurantItem(r = it, modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth(0.8f))
    }
}
```

Comment: You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69608517/scroll-two-lazy-scrollers-together) instead. It would be simpler

Comment: @MARSK Nice, but has animation lag.

Comment: No it doesn't on my device. It works quite smooth. Are you trying on an emulator?

Comment: I suggested since the modification is specific to `LazyVerticalGrid`, while the link offers all round customisation.

Comment: Okay. Yes, It was on emulator. If it had worked on emulator, it would ensure to work well on low-end devices too.

Comment: I wouldn't count on that. Emulators mimic minimal system resources, but they are not able to mimic it efficiently, depending on the hardware of the PC you are running them on. So you cannot expect an emulator to give accurate results of the exact same physical model. I have seen emulators become non-responsive on very-bootup. I have also seen them take minutes to open up the main app launcher (the drawer where all the apps are stored)

Comment: Emulators will always be slower. It has to do with compilation and runtime optimizations.