# Scroll Two Lazy Scrollers Together

Tags: android, state, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list, android-jetpack-compose-modifier

This question has been asked before, but in different forms, regarding some specific use cases, and so far there has been no answer. I finally got it working, so I am sharing this here, but this should not be marked as a duplicate since all the previous questions specify specific stuff, like `Columns` with `scrollable` `Modifiers`, or `LazyRows`, but this will resolve all the issues in general, I mean all the lazy-scrollers, and hopefully even scrollable containers in general. I'll post the answer so this is just a piece of knowledge that I wished to share with the community, also, any improvements are welcome, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the full working solution:-

```
@Composable
fun DUME() {

    val stateRowX = rememberLazyListState() // State for the first Row, X
    val stateRowY = rememberLazyListState() // State for the second Row, Y

    Column { // Placing two Lazy Rows one above the other for the example

        LazyRow(state = stateRowY) {
            items(LoremIpsum(10).values.toList()) {
                Text(it)
            }
        }

        LazyRow(state = stateRowX) {
            items(LoremIpsum(10).values.toList()) {
                Text(text = it)
            }
        }

    }

    //This might seem crazy

    LaunchedEffect(stateRowX.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset) {
        stateRowY.scrollToItem(
            stateRowX.firstVisibleItemIndex,
            stateRowX.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
        )
    }

    LaunchedEffect(stateRowY.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset) {
        stateRowX.scrollToItem(
            stateRowY.firstVisibleItemIndex,
            stateRowY.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
        )
    }
}
```

The `items` import here is : `androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items`, this accepts a list instead of a number (the size).

Comment: Just want to translate the `    //This might seem crazy` 

It is actually very elegant. Basically it says: if lazy row X is updated (by detecting changes in the scrollable offset of the first item), we move Y to make it the same as X. 

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects

Comment: You have recursion calls between states, one change calls another, another calls one etc until: 
1. Whole this thing starts to lag.
2. Inertia is lost. Your solution have none at all.
You need to block recursion calls.

Comment: I appreciate you sharing your thoughts here. Did you run the code on a device? It seems like recursion, but the blocks are executed very efficiently. I personally experienced no lag. As far as inertia is concerned, I'll check once, but I think even that was preserved here.

Comment: This code works but if you have two lists, one with few items than other, then  the smaller list will stop as soon as it reaches end. e.g.:  lists are :     val nums = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
        val chars = listOf('a', 'b', 'c').  So, I guess I am basically asking for how to scroll the smaller list beyond the first item until the end of longer list. Please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Another working approach, which can also be applied to more than two lazy scrollers.

```
@Composable
fun DUME() {

    val stateRowX = rememberLazyListState() // State for the first Row, X
    val stateRowY = rememberLazyListState() // State for the second Row, Y
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val scrollState = rememberScrollableState { delta ->
        scope.launch {
            stateRowX.scrollBy(-delta)
            stateRowY.scrollBy(-delta)
        }
        delta
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.scrollable(scrollState, Orientation.Horizontal, flingBehavior = ScrollableDefaults.flingBehavior())
    ) { 

        LazyRow(
            state = stateRowX,
            userScrollEnabled = false
        ) {
            items(LoremIpsum(10).values.toList()) {
                Text(text = it)
            }
        }

        LazyRow(
            state = stateRowY,
            userScrollEnabled = false
        ) {
            items(LoremIpsum(10).values.toList()) {
                Text(text = it)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this looks to have more performance than the accepted answer. Also, I think it can become more clear by putting into a Box container.

Comment: @MrCurious i dont see userScrollEnabled = false in LazyRow. What is that?

Comment: @anshul You can find it here https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary under the LazyRow section.

Comment: @MrCurious thanks for the reply. it is available with the latest version. But this solution doesn't seem to be working with a more complex use cases as i have here https://pastebin.com/FKMh0xhC

Answer (score 3):

The above answer by Richard is good but it creates lags when scrolling because of the loop it creates as described by Ivan. The solution is simple for that problem

```
LaunchedEffect(stateRowX.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset) {
    if (!stateRowY.isScrollInProgress) {
        stateRowY.scrollToItem(
            stateRowX.firstVisibleItemIndex,
            stateRowX.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
        )
    }
}

LaunchedEffect(stateRowY.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset) {
    if (!stateRowX.isScrollInProgress) {
        stateRowX.scrollToItem(
            stateRowY.firstVisibleItemIndex,
            stateRowY.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
        )
    }
}
```

Now it will not lag while scrolling.