# Jetpack compose how to make two lazy columns scroll together

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to have two columns of card flow in the screen with paging data from network. I have tried using two lazy columns with launch effects. (ref: [Scroll Two Lazy Scrollers Together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69608517/scroll-two-lazy-scrollers-together)), however, the height of card is different so I cannot use the firstVisibleItemScrollOffset and firstVisibleItemIndex directly. If I use lazyGrid, the height of the card cannot be different. How to implement a two-column card flow page like this?

[target data flow page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z91JV.png)

how to make two lazy column scroll together or combine swipe refresh layout with column when using jetpack compose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a [**`LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/staggeredgrid/package-summary#LazyHorizontalStaggeredGrid(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.staggeredgrid.StaggeredGridCells,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.staggeredgrid.LazyStaggeredGridState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)).

Something like:

```
val state = rememberLazyStaggeredGridState()

LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
    columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    state = state,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
    content = {

        items(count) {
            //item content
        }
    }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to pass as an argument the same LazyListState to both LazyColumns?

Comment: I have tried but they cannot scroll together

Comment: I did this and it worked. I used one list state, using `rememberLazyListState()`, and passed that list state to both instances of `LazyColumn`. After doing this, the columns scrolled together.